# How can I properly display CKEditor 4.0 toolbar drop-down menus and other popups in a window?

Tags: drop-down-menu, ckeditor, z-index

I have a kendo UI window (but I think jquery UI window/dialog will result in same issue). I have a CKEditor 4.0 in the window. Drop-down menus such as font, style, etc. and context menus initially display when clicked. However, after clicking in the text area, the drop down will fail to display when clicked on again.

I only see this issue with CKEditor 4.0. Version 3.6 seems fine. Does anyone know of a workaround to this issue in 4.0? I'm aware of CKEDITOR.config.baseFloatZIndex but even setting it to a zindex above the zindex of the window/dialog still results in the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get it working with config.baseFloatZIndex = 102000;
but as you say, this doesn't work for you.